# I'm using vuetify and want to render array of objects inside a array of object in a drop down button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Imangine I have a json object like this:

```
listofSubdomains:[{
  "name": "domain1",
  "subdomain": [
    {
      "name": "subdomain1"
    },
    {
      "name": "subdomain2"
    }
  ],
  "document": [
    {
      "name": "doc1"
    },
   {
      "name": "doc2"
   }
  ]
}]
```

So if I want to render subdomain key under listofSubdomains in vue for dropdown: like this -

```
<v-overflow-btn class="my-2" :items="listofSubdomains.subdomain" v-model='itemSelectSubDomain' item-text="name" item-value="name" label="Overflow Btn" target="#dropdown-example"></v-overflow-btn>
```

How will I do this as ":items" attribute value that I have given doesnt work. or do I have to go ahead and use loops only?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that this is what you are looking for, but this should work.

```
 <v-overflow-btn
  v-for="(domain, index) in listofSubdomains.subdomain" :key="index"
  class="my-2"
  v-model='itemSelectSubDomain'
  :item-text="domain.name"
  :item-value="domain.name"
  label="Overflow Btn"
  target="#dropdown-example">
</v-overflow-btn>
```

Good Luck